# Packaging Videos Within An App

Tags: android

I am in the process of developing a fitness app.  I want the user to have the option to view a demonstration video of each exercise (of which there are ten).  I am currently accessing YouTube videos for the demonstrations.  I filmed people at my gym doing the movements today and I am curious what would be the best way to package these videos within my application.  I'm assuming I can include them in my drawables and access them from there.  Also, what type of files should I make them?  The videos will each be less than 30 seconds so I don't think they will take up too much space in the application, but I could be wrong.  Anyway, any advice would be welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them into the raw folder (/res/raw). Create it if needed.
Supported formats are 3gp and mp4.

To play them you can use:

```
 VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
    view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    view.start();
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done that once for one of the assignments in my mobile apps class last semester so hopefully it won't present too much of a problem.

Comment: Do you think there will be an issue with the videos taking up too much space on a device?  There are ten videos and they should be about 30-40 seconds each.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem on most devices. However, what is the total size of your videos?